Detecting merged cells in an Excel spreadsheet when in read-only mode
In openpyxl, there's no way to detect merged cells while in read_only mode (crucial for dealing with large Excel files in a reasonable manner). The top comment on this question reminds readers that:

Note for future readers: don't load_workbook(..., read_only=True) as information regarding merged cells is unavailable in read-only mode.

Are there other libraries or engines which retain merged cell information in a read-only mode? Or is there a solution using openpyxl that allows one to retain such information?

Seems like this question was asked just recently but appears to have disappeared. Unzip the xlsx and look for mergeCell in the Sheet xml files e.g. <mergeCell ref="B35:F37"/>
